# AtomicCSS - How to make a fade-in animation?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using the AtomicCSS framework from acss.io, so far so good.

However, I am stuck with creating animations. The reference page is silent about it and the examples page does not deliver any examples.

https://acss.io/reference.html

https://acss.io/guides/syntax.html#examples-

Let this be a starting point of my animation and show what I am looking for(fade in):

```
    @keyframes fadeIn {
      from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, -20%, 0);
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -20%, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Animn(fadeIn)"></div>
```